# Visible binding - knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to control the visibility of an element (the yellow box in the fiddle code below) using 3 images with click events. It is not working.

I defined the following visibility properties

```
    IsSelectionPoll = ko.observable(true);
    IsBoolPoll = ko.observable();
    IsRatePoll = ko.observable();
```

Here is the click event:

```
SetTypeId = function (typeId) {
  //selectPollType = typeId;
  $('<p/>').text(typeId).appendTo('body');
  IsSelectionPoll = (typeId == '1');
  console.log(typeId);
  IsBoolPoll = (typeId == '3');
  IsRatePoll = (typeId == '2');
 }
```

I tried using the SELF and the this and many other tricks but I can't figure out why it is not working.

Please view the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/goldenrate/NfDyX/

thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating any view model in there - change the function declaration to:

```
function PollWizardViewModel(initialData){
```

and then the binding line to:

```
 ko.applyBindings(new PollWizardViewModel());
```

The click binding itself should work as it is once that is done.

**Edit**: also, do not reassign your observables, but simply change their values, otherwise the binding with the dom is lost (since the link is with the old observables that are discared when you reassign their reference) - e.g. instead of:

```
this.IsSelectionPoll = (typeId == '1');
```

use:

```
this.IsSelectionPoll(typeId == '1');
```

Comment: Thank you. The click binding works as you can tell by the rendered results (I add $('<p/>').text(typeId).appendTo('body');), but I also fixed the definition as per your recommendation and it is still not working.

Comment: You're right, there was a problem with the observable setting too - I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I applied the changes here http://jsfiddle.net/goldenrate/NfDyX/12/ and also reorganized the code but it simply doesn't work. It's very simple task that I did many times in the past and I can't figure out what is the problem.

Comment: You were setting up the variables in the global object (window) and then trying to catch them from the ViewModel function (and not the *instance* you created). I updated your fiddle to show what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/NfDyX/13/ - note the *this* both in the constructor and in the settypeid function and the fact that the function itself is assigned to the view model prototype. Hope that helps.